# Compiliing and executing Java programs in OSX

Tags: java, macos, rsa

Someone needs a public RSA key from me & gave me a java program to make a keypair. I have zero experience with Java so very simple things are very difficult for me. The program looks like this:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.NoSuchProviderException;
import java.security.Provider;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateKey;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey;
import java.security.spec.RSAPrivateKeySpec;
import java.security.spec.RSAPublicKeySpec;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
public class CustomRSAKeyPairGenerator{
 public void generate() {
    try {
        KeyPairGenerator objlRSAKeyPairGen =
        KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        objlRSAKeyPairGen.initialize(2048);
        KeyPair objlRSAKeyPair = objlRSAKeyPairGen.generateKeyPair();
        RSAPublicKey objlPublicKey = (RSAPublicKey) objlRSAKeyPair.getPublic();
        RSAPrivateKey objlPrivateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) objlRSAKeyPair.getPrivate();
        StringBuffer strblPublicKey = new StringBuffer();
        strblPublicKey.append(objlPublicKey.getModulus().toString(16).toUpperCase());
        strblPublicKey.append('~');
        strblPublicKey.append(objlPublicKey.getPublicExponent().toString(16).toUpperCase()
    ); 
    System.out.println(strblPublicKey.toString());
    StringBuffer strblPrivateKey = new StringBuffer();
    strblPrivateKey.append(objlPrivateKey.getModulus().toString(16).toUpperCase());
    strblPrivateKey.append('~');
    strblPrivateKey.append(objlPrivateKey.getPrivateExponent().toString(16).toUpperCase());
    System.out.println(strblPrivateKey.toString()); 
    }catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException noSuchAlgrtm){
        System.out.println(noSuchAlgrtm.getMessage());
    }
 }
}
```

When I compile this I get a file called "CustomRSAKeyPairGenerator.class" so I then run that like this:

```
mylogin$java CustomRSAKeyPairGenerator
```

and I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: CustomRSAKeyPairGenerator/class
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: CustomRSAKeyPairGenerator.class
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

Am I running this wrong or is there a problem in the java source that I need to fix? Is there a way to use this to make the RSA keypair that I need?

Comment: Based on the exception, you're command line example doesn't match. Make sure 1- the code is compiled; 2- You are in the same directory as the .class file; 3- You're specifying the name of the class without the .class extension when running it

Comment: It doesn't seem like there's an error in the code big enough to cause that, though it's not exactly the cleanest code in the world. How exactly did you compile it?

Comment: @pg. Use the @ sign to target replies.

Comment: @raptortech I wrote it into a file and then cd'ed to that dir and then "javac CustomRSAKeyPairGenerator.java"

Comment: @madprogrammer How do I specify the name of the class without the class exception when running it?

Comment: Well, your pasted command line "should" work, `java CustomRSAKeyPairGenerator`, assuming the source file has been compiled AND your are in the same directory as the resulting `.class` file